# `SliverGrid` throws Exception after all children are removed from list

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm dynamically removing children from a `SliverGrid.count` but when all children are removed the `SliverGrid` throws the Exception `SliverGeometry is not valid: The "scrollExtent" is negative.`
I think this error happens because when the list of children is empty the `Grid` has no children to render anymore and can't render itself. When I also just place a `Container` (which isn't removable) at the top of my dynamic list of children the error doesn't happen but the rest of my children get pushed down becuase of the `AxisSpacing`.

Is there another way to fix this issue than just placing a static `Container at the top or bottom of the children?

This is the code from my `SliverGrid` and the layout is also shown in an image below:

```
SliverGrid.count(
  mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
  crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
  crossAxisCount: segmentedControlGroupValue,
  children: <Widget>[
    for (var i = 0;
        i < sessionState.patientQuestionnaires.length;
        i++)
      Material(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
        elevation: 6,
        shadowColor: Colors.black38,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () => showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            isScrollControlled: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            builder: (context) => PQBottomSheet(
              i: i,
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
            child: Row(children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Wrap(
                  runAlignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                  alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.assignment,
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      size: segmentedControlGroupValue == 1
                          ? 30
                          : segmentedControlGroupValue == 2
                              ? 28
                              : 24,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      sessionState.patientQuestionnaires[i]
                          .credentialSubject.documentName,
                      style:
                          Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      DateFormat.yMMMd().format(DateTime.parse(
                              sessionState
                                  .patientQuestionnaires[i]
                                  .issuanceDate)
                          .toLocal()),
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .bodyText2!
                          .copyWith(
                            color: Theme.of(context)
                                .colorScheme
                                .onBackground
                                .withOpacity(0.5),
                          ),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
                  onPressed: () => Platform.isAndroid
                      ? showCupertinoModalPopup(
                          useRootNavigator: false,
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) =>
                              CupertinoActionSheet(
                            actions: [
                              CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                child: Text(L.of(context).share),
                              ),
                              CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                  setState(() {
                                    context
                                        .read<SessionCubit>()
                                        .deletePQ(
                                            i, sessionState);
                                  });
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                  L.of(context).delete,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Theme.of(context)
                                          .errorColor),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                            cancelButton:
                                CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                              onPressed: () =>
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                              child: Text(
                                L.of(context).cancel,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      : bottomSheet(
                          context: context,
                          buttons: [
                            SizedBox(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              child: TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                child: Text(L.of(context).share,
                                    style: Theme.of(context)
                                        .textTheme
                                        .bodyText1),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              child: TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                  setState(() {
                                    context
                                        .read<SessionCubit>()
                                        .deletePQ(
                                            i, sessionState);
                                  });
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                  L.of(context).delete,
                                  style: Theme.of(context)
                                      .textTheme
                                      .bodyText1!
                                      .copyWith(
                                        color: Theme.of(context)
                                            .errorColor,
                                      ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert))
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
  ],
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Removing the complete `SilverGrid` widget when there are no items present might work. Because there has to be at least one widget inside the Grid.

```dart
if (sessionState.patientQuestionnaires.length > 0)
  SilverGrid.count(...),
```

Adding the above code will make the `SilverGrid` disappear and again appear when you add some content to the `patientQuestionnaires`.

Note: You need to `setState()` or an alternative to refresh the state when the item is removed/added. (Hopefully, you are already using one)